# How to typedef a structure including pointers to itself?

Tags: c, structure, typedef

Code without `typedef` (and it works):

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};
```

I'm trying to make a code using `typedef` for the structure "Node" in Doubly Linked List, but this does not work:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
} Node;
```

Is there a way around this using `typedef`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the typedef, the to-be-defined type is not yet known, so you need to introduce and use a struct tag:

```
typedef struct Node_tag {
    int data;
    struct Node_tag *next;
    struct Node_tag *prev;
} Node;
```

The `Node_tag` is the struct tag, because of where it is introduced (and not because of the name part "_tag"). It is not a type in itself, only the combination as `struct Node_tag` is a type which can be used for the struct members.
Afterwards, when the typedef is done, the type `Node` has been defined.
To clarify, a second typedef would be possible as `typedef struct Node_tag NodeToo;`. This demonstrates that the type `struct Node_tag` is also useable. That is why I prefer to use the "_tag" name fragment, to allow to be clear of what is used.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a forward declaration of the struct

```
typedef struct sNode Node; // this is a typedef and a declaration of the struct
struct sNode{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```

This way `Node` is known (but not defined), in the definition of your `struct`.

This can be compressed as it is done by Yunnosch. But then you need to use the `struct Name` notation inside your declaration.

This way it is possible to already use the typedefed name also the forward declaration is necessary if you have some circular dependencies in your structs.

It is also possible to use the struct name as the typedef:

```
typedef struct Node Node; 
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```

I personally prefer the first style, it seems "clearer" to me, but there is nothing wrong with the second example, as long as the [compiler is not from the pre-standard era (before 1989)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/310302).

As Jens Gustedt pointed out the first style might be incompatible if this is included in C++.

So maybe I should change my preference to the first.

Comment: [yes, they can be used for reserved names](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html)

Comment: @JHBonarius Nice link, I added it to my SO link-library.

Comment: There is not much reason to use `struct sNode`. `struct Node`, that is the same identifier for the tag as for the `typedef` is sufficient.

Comment: @JensGustedt I know that it is common practice to use the same name with and without struct. But I think it is "dirty" and there are some guidelines that enforce different names. Yet I do not know how common they are.

Comment: @JensGustedt [As it seems there might even be some problems with this practice.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/310302) Thanks to JHBonarius

Comment: @KamiKaze Yet these problems were with **pre-standart C compilers**. For new code, this should be a non-issue. I have never run into problems with `typedef struct Foo {} Foo;`.

Comment: Just to put that into context, pre-standard refers to compilers that have not got around to become standard conforming for about 30 years. And no, this is not *dirty*, this is just the way it should be. Having different names for the same type is highly confusing, and typedeffing to the same identifier is the thing to do if you want to be header compatible with C++.

Comment: @JensGustedt I included this in my answer, still this is C and is valid in this. There are other things that are perfectly valid C that break a C++ compiler (not casting malloc afaik), so C++ compatibility is nice to have (or sometimes mandatory), but is not a metric for C code in itself.

Comment: @KamiKaze, that is why I said "header compatible".

Answer (score 1):

Inside the structure, you have indeed to use types that are already known by the compiler. A way to be compliant with this rule in your case is to **use the `struct Node *` type after having declared `typedef struct Node`**. In this case, even if the type `struct Node` is incompletely defined when the compiler encounters it inside the structure, the name is known and the compiler knows the size of a pointer (to reserve in memory), so it has no reason to complain !
Morevover it is also accepted to use the same name for the type as after `struct`: you can use `Node` for both.
Here is my suggested solution:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

Comment: Although supported, I don't consider it good practice to give the struct the same name as the type. [It's discouraged for compatibility (with ancient compilers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/310302)

Comment: @Laurent Okay, thank you! Unfortunately, I've chosen to pick another answer. Nevertheless, your explanation helps a lot and I've upvoted your answer :-)

Comment: @WealthyPlayer You're welcome, thanks for your upvote. My answer was indeed a bit late, but I tried it to be complete. Glad to see that it was helpful !

Comment: @WealthyPlayer Generally you are not bound to your first decision of the selected answer. You should pick what you think is appropiate.

Comment: @Kami Noted :-D Sorry for the very late comment response.